# How to detect .Net 4 Full Profile

Tags: .net-4.0

How can you detect whether a PC has the .Net 4 Full Profile installed, as opposed to the .Net 4 Client Profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the [registry keys](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/detection-keys-for-net-framework-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010/). Also if your application is targeting the full .NET 4.0 profile and this profile is not installed you will probably not go as far as checking the registry keys because your application won't run at all. So this check is better to be done when deploying the application on the client machine as part of the setup and deployment project. You could use a launch condition:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Darin - that does the trick.  I'm using Tarma installer, so will access the registry keys from the installer.

Comment: You might also do this if you have an umanaged splash window launcher application.